# Can CC interactions be used to detect oscillations $\bar{\nu_e} \to \bar{\nu_\mu}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, neutrinos

Can CC interactions be used to detect  oscillations $\bar{\nu_e} \to \bar{\nu_\mu}$?

I believe this is not possible because CC interactions occur through the emission of a $W_{\pm}$ boson. This would not respect charge conservation because the neutrinos are neutrally charged and the $W_{\pm}$ has got charge $\pm 1$.

Is my "theory" correct or am I missing a point?

Comment: Do you mean 'detect' - for which the answer is yes - or 'produce' - for which the answer is no?

Comment: Your $\bar \nu _\mu$ transmutes to a real $\mu^+$ and a virtual $W^-$ in your detector, conserving charge. The virtual *W* is absorbed by a proton, transmuting it to another one nucleon (neutron). What, exactly, is your theory?

Comment: Cosmos Zachos , I thought that in the diagram the neutrinos had to be connected at the same vertex in the Feynman diagram, it was a silly presumption from my lecturer's diagrams. That makes perfect sense. Thank you for your help

Comment: RogerJBarlow the question specifically says detect, but what would the difference be? Does Cosmas Zachos given reaction correspond to a detection or production? Thank you for your help